# ChartJS loading errors from axios API call in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I am trying to render charts for a dashboard made in Vue.JS and I have a flask API set as a dummy backend.

I'm following the tutorial on https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data and am having trouble rendering my visualisations.

My component code is:

```
<template>
  <Bar
    v-if="loaded"
    :data="chartData"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'
import axios from 'axios'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  data: () => ({
    loaded: false,
    chartData: null
  }),
  async mounted () {
    this.loaded = false

    axios.get('/genres')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
        this.chartData = { labels: res.data.labels, dataset: [{ data: res.data.data }] }
        this.loaded = true
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

I am getting the following in the console:

```
handled error during execution of mounted hook 
  at <Anonymous ref=fn<reforwardRef> type="bar" data= Object  ... > 
  at <Bar key=0 data= Object > 
  at <BarChart> 
  at <AboutView onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
w
```

and

```
ils.ts:60 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at setDatasets (utils.ts:60:1)
    at cloneData (utils.ts:97:1)
    at renderChart (chart.ts:35:1)
    at eval (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2756:1)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:173:1)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:182:1)
    at hook.__weh.hook.__weh (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2731:1)
    at flushPostFlushCbs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:359:1)
    at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:413:1)
```

I don't know where these errors are coming from as I'm quite new to JS / Vue / Chart.JS, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `vue-chartjs`; more precisely from line 60 of the function `setDatasets`, which is defined inside the file [`utils.ts`](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/blob/main/src/utils.ts).

The problem can most probably be solved if you change the following line of your code.

```
this.chartData = { labels: res.data.labels, dataset: [{ data: res.data.data }] }
```

Instead of `dataset`, specify `datasets` as follows:

```
this.chartData = { labels: res.data.labels, datasets: [{ data: res.data.data }] }
```

If this doesn't help, the structure of `res.data.data` needs to be checked. Make sure, it complies with one of the [formats expected by Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html).